# VSTO Remapping the close window button

Tags: vsto

I'm creating a vsto excel add-in and I'm trying to find a way to either change the current functionality or add the ability to call a function when the close window button is pressed for the current spreadsheet. Does anyone know if this is possible or have any suggestions? I haven't been able to find much of anything thus far.

Answer (score 0):

The Workbook class has an event called BeforeClose, which you can use to detect when a workbook is being closed. You can also use this event to stop it from being closed by setting the Cancel parameter to true.

To detect this event on the current workbook, you have to attach an event handler for the BeforeClose event on the current workbook.

The simplest way is to attach an event handler to the BeforeClose event when the Application.WorkbookActivate is raised. And detach it from the previously active workbook.

e.g.

```
private Workbook _activeWorkbook = null;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application.WorkbookActivate += Application_WorkbookActivate;

    // Attach to the BeforeClose event on the Workbook that 
    // was created when Excel started
    _activeWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook;
    if (_activeWorkbook != null)
    {
        _activeWorkbook.BeforeClose += ActiveWorkbook_BeforeClose;
    }
}

private void Application_WorkbookActivate(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
    if (_activeWorkbook != null)
    {
        _activeWorkbook.BeforeClose -= ActiveWorkbook_BeforeClose;
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_activeWorkbook);
    }

    _activeWorkbook = Wb;
    _activeWorkbook.BeforeClose += ActiveWorkbook_BeforeClose;
}

private void ActiveWorkbook_BeforeClose(ref bool Cancel)
{
    Cancel = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close the workbook?", "Close Workbook", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) != DialogResult.Yes;
}
```

So if you want to change the current functionality or add the ability to call a function when the close window button is pressed for the current spreadsheet, add your code in the ActiveWorkbook_BeforeClose method.